# Linux - launch recordMyDesktop by ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel, xserver

I made a script (name : "recordVideo") that launch recordMyDesktop to capture a window. this script is on a computer-1. With computer-2 I want to launch the script with ssh.
Here is my script on computer-1 :

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ivtuser/Bureau/
recordmydesktop --no-sound --delay 3 --windowid &(xwininfo -name "NAME_OF_WINDOW" | sed -n 's/.*Window id: \([0-9a-fx]\+\).*/\1/p')
```

I have set my parameters for ssh in ssh_config :

```
ForwardX11 yes
```

and sshd_config :

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

And Xauth is installed on my PC.
I tried to launch in local mode for my test with ssh with this command :

```
$ ssh -X localhost
password: XXX
$ recordVideo
```

And here is my problem, recordmydesktop stop with the response :

```
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
```

How can I fix this. I'm lost
Thanks

Comment: does the same script work from computer 1, without ssh? If it doesn't, then its a user permission issue, most probably the user you are sshing into doesn't have adequate permissions on the device.

Comment: are you using with script with proper superuser privilages...

Comment: what happens when you run `ssh -X computer-1 xterm` or `ssh -X computer-1 xdpyinfo`?

Comment: @mu & shiv garg : I can run my script on the computer without the superuser privilages and it works. I have the problem only when using ssh.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla : for the moment I tested only with one computer, running ssh in localhost. I don't have yet the 2 computers where it will be installed.

Comment: This might fail when the user that started X and the user who runs the script are different. X tries to make it hard for people to spy on a remote desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. SUID
2. SSH as root

The first one is hard to get right without exposing your computer to security risks.

The second solution uses `ssh root@computer-1 /path/to/recordVideo` to log in as root and run the script as root.

Also make sure the `$DISPLAY` variable is correctly set. `ssh -X` should do that for you or you need to specify the option `-display LOCAL:0.0` to all commands which connect to the X server (where `LOCAL` is the IP address or DNS name of the computer that you're sitting in front of).

Comment: I tried ssh in root mode, and I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: Also make sure that `$DISPLAY` is set correctly on the remote side.

Comment: I tried ForwardX11Trusted yes : same problem
I don't understand your "$DISPLAY" thing. How can I check it ?

Comment: The `$DISPLAY` variable tells the X client to which server it should talk to. In your case, you want to connect to the X server running on computer-2. But `ssh` prepares everything so that the client connects to X on the computer where you run `ssh`. You really need two computers to test this. How about setting up a virtual machine?

Comment: Ok, I'll test it as soon as possible with the two computers. I didn't think about a VM, if it's simple to set up, I should try it. thank you, I'll let you know the results.

Comment: You were wright with your last answer, I tested with two computers, adding to my script the DISPLAY variable and it works. `recordmydesktop --no-sound --delay 3 --windowid &(xwininfo -name "NAME_OF_WINDOW" -display NAME_COMPUTER:0.0 | sed -n 's/.*Window id: \([0-9a-fx]\+\).*/\1/p') --display NAME_COMPUTER:0.0`